# Change how a phone identifies itself on the network

Tags: nexus-5, networking, mobile-network, moto-x

I currently own a Nexus 5. My mobile carrier just now begun providing LTE, but my Nexus 5 apparently isn't in its "list of compatible devices". Is there a way for me to change how the network identifies my phone, and have it be identified as a Moto X for example?

Comment: Does the N5 actually support your carrier's LTE bands? If it's *physically* incompatible then there's nothing you can do.